# Starting a Background Process for a Python code

Tags: python, syntax, background-process, spawn

I am currently running a python code from the command line with this command:

**python fileName.py myUserID myPassword > logFile_date**

Is there a similar command that I can use to either run this process in the background or spawn a process to run in the background?

Thanks,
Ramani

Comment: `python fileName.py myUserID myPassword > logFile_ &`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cronjob to run a script in the background. You can specify it to run at certain intervals or at certain times (here's the ubuntu [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto))

For example, here's what your cronjob might look like:

`*/10 * * * * /your/path/to/python /path/to/fileName.py >> /path/to/logFile_date.txt`

This will run your script every 10 minutes and have the output saved to logFile_date.txt, all in the background.